# Comicmind Material Framework button event handler

Tags: ios, cosmicmind

I would just like to ask, how can I handle events of the Material Button using cosmicmind/Material? I currently have this code. Now, I want to do a function when user taps or clicked the button. Thank you!

```
fileprivate func prepareRaisedButton() {
        let button = RaisedButton(title: "Create an account", titleColor : .white)
        button.pulseColor = .white
        button.backgroundColor = Color.teal.base

        view.layout(button)
            .height(ButtonLayout.Raised.height)
            .top(18 * constant).horizontally(left : constant, right : constant)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you want is inherited from [UIControl](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget):

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapButton), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: One more thing, how can I get the textfield value? email.text isn't working